# How to stop barchart from hiding labels for data value 0 in Mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, bar-chart, mathematica-8

I use this to create a Bar Chart:

```
BarChart[
 Reverse@data,
 BarOrigin -> Left,
 ChartLabels -> 
  Placed[{Reverse@labels, Reverse@data}, {Before, After}],
 ChartElementFunction -> "FadingRectangle"
 ]
```

With `data = {7, 10, 0, 6, 0, 3, 5}` this gives

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The problem is that some of the data values are 0 and `BarChart` won't even add labels for them. Instead it leaves a open space. How can I get it to still add the labels even though the values are 0?

This is with Mathematica 8.

Comment: Possibly related: [Not cropping BarChart when using Frame instead of Axes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6557883/not-cropping-barchart-when-using-frame-instead-of-axes)

Comment: It's a rough workaround, but if nothing better comes up, you can do `BarChart[Reverse[data /. x_ /; x == 0 -> 10^-5], ...` (i.e. replace zeros with small numbers just before plotting).  I used the pattern `x_ /; x == 0` to match both 0 and 0.0 ... I guess 0|0.0 would have been good as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about

```
data = {7, 10, 0, 6, 0, 3, 5}

labels = ("label " ~~ ToString[#]) & /@ data

BarChart[Reverse@data, BarOrigin -> Left,
ChartLabels -> Placed[{Reverse@labels, Reverse@data}, {Axis, After}],
ChartElementFunction -> "FadingRectangle"]
```

It seems that "Before" doesn't and "Axis" does work?

[image: chart]

Comment: This looks like the cleanest solution, even if you still loose the second labels.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest approach is to use a hack like `data /. {(0|0.0) -> 0.00001}`.

I think this should work without the need for a hack, so you should also file a report with support@wolfram.com.

Comment: I realize I made a mistake when I edited a sample dataset and plot into the question: the dataset might be real numbers, so `0|0.0 -> 0.00001` or something similar would be better.

Comment: @Szabolcs Good point.  I added your approach (after briefly considering `PossibleZeroQ`...)

Answer (score 2):

Your code works as given in *Mathematica* 7 on Windows 7.

```
data = {7, 10, 0, 6, 0, 3, 5};

labels = Row[{"label",#}]& /@ data;

BarChart[
  Reverse@data,
  BarOrigin -> Left,
  ChartLabels ->
   Placed[{Reverse@labels, Reverse@data}, {Before, After}],
  ChartElementFunction -> "FadingRectangle"
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I suppose I should have specified I'm using Mathematica 8.